# Registering a domain directly at nic.sm?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar, registration, domains

I am an individual and would like to register a ".sm" domain.

Nic.sm provides forms for individuals to send them by fax or mail and information for payment is also available. The cheapest reseller that I found wants 135 EUR per year, whereas the cost at nic.sm is only 50 EUR a year.

EDIT:
The lengthy rules at nic.sm mention that they deal only with authorized resellers themselves.
However, nic.sm links to Telecom Italia San Marino as an authorized reseller (at the top of the link list, in bold). Telecom Italia seems to follow the exact same procedures as nic.sm (the difference being that you send the forms to them instead of nic.sm).

So the question remains: does Telecom Italia San Marino deal with private individuals directly?
I wrote them an email some days ago with no reply.

Answer (score 3):

There are certain CCTLDs that are offered directly to the customers by the Registrar. 
Registries like Verisign(for .COM and .NET) follow the Registry->Registrar model.

A Registrar uses channels to register the domain names for the end clients.

The Registry sells the domain names through its network of accredited Registrars(accredited by ICANN)

Telecom Italia San Marino deals with private individuals. They will definitely respond to your e-mail.

Comment: Well, it's been a week now since I emailed them. No reply, yet. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: now that is not done. I will check the details once and revert.

Comment: Never got a reply from them. Maybe I should have sent them a fax, because their processes are totally antiquated.

Answer (score 2):

Generally resellers will have receive products and services cheaper than they are sold direct and they make margins this way, however this wouldn't seem the case unless they are just plain greedy. Go direct and order the domain nic.sm there is little difference in terms of usage since both will have control panels for setting up records.

While asking on here is great its also worth noting that we are not always right either so another bit of advice would be to email this 'Reseller' and ask why they are charging 135 Euro compared to nic.sm maybe they can advise reasons why and what they offer, they might use Premium DNS services which gives better SLA uptime on the DNS, but I doubt it - worth asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason why the reseller would charge more is obvious - a profit markup on the wholesale price. I've seen .sm domains offered by a reseller for 250 EUR a year. As far as I know, the domain registry will not offer a control panel. You have to send them a fax or a letter to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

I always check out this website before buying domain names - www.change-domain.com - My personal favourite is godaddy because they're the simplest and usually the cheapest for new domain registrations.